# Масштабирование Windows и Android studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, windows-10

Мне необходимо поставить масштабирование экрана в Windows на 200%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом у меня криво работает эмуляция телефона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если поставить масштабирование в Windows на 100%, то проблема уйдет, но мне нужно именно 200%
Может кто знает как это исправить?